# How to change class character to class date in R without getting NA results

Tags: r

I've got a data table with a column of dates: `ex_dates <- c("2022-01-01", "2022-05-28")`
they are now at class character, how can I change them to class date?

I've tried this code:

```
data$date <-  as.Date(data$date,"%d/%m/%Y")
```

but it changes the whole column to NA.

Comment: The `%`-codes are documented in [`?strptime`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strptime.html), which is mentioned several times in [`?as.Date`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/as.Date.html), specifically *"processing is via `strptime()` whose help page describes available conversion specifications"*.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use base R, you need to specify the correct format.

`%d/%m/%Y` is expecting dates in the following format: `01/12/2020`

But in your example, years come before months and before days, and these are separated by a `-`, not a `/`. So you need to change to the following:

```r
data$date <- c("2022-01-01", "2022-05-28")
data$date <-  as.Date(data$date, "%Y-%m-%d")
```

Because this is the standard format, you could also avoid specifying it:

```r
data$date <-  as.Date(data$date)
```

(Personally I always use `lubridate` as it's much easier).

Answer (score 0):

The `as.Date()` function expects your actual date format.

Your ex_dates are `%Y-%m-%d` not `"%d/%m/%Y"` thats why you got `NA's`

The correct way would be

```
data$date <-  as.Date(data$date,format = "%Y-%m-%d")
```

I see alot of peaple who thinks the format argument in `as.Date()` is a transformating parameter. But no, its just yout helping the `as.Date()` to recognize the date aspects on your vector.